# Apache Site configuration failed to load resources

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache, config, vhosts

I'm trying to vhost a WordPress site that is located in a folder with the path

> /var/www/html/wordpress

I have disabled the 000-default.config and created the following configuration file for exposing this website to port 80

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin Test_Backend@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This Configuration are located in

> etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf

The site seems hosted now but resources are not loading.

[image]

[image]

Can you please let me know how I can correct this?

Answer (score 0):

probably file permission errors, check here

https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-file-permissions/.

Make sure you enforce right permissions to make your resources available to the outside.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/wordpress
sudo find /var/www/wordpress/ -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/wordpress/ -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \;
```

provided your php and apache, apache mods are functioning alright.

Comment: addendum: enable URL rewriting with `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and restart apache2 with `sudo service apache2 restart`